# mod_pagespeed and java app servers

Tags: java, tomcat, apache2, mod-pagespeed

Can one use mod_pagespeed with tomcat application server? directly or indirectly?

Am i correct in stating that you can use mod_pagespeed with tomcat if you use apache webserver as a proxy to tomcat webserver? (does this work with mod_jk?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mod_pagespeed with Tomcat. You're right that you'll need to use Apache as a proxy to Tomcat. I know that it definitely works with mod_jk since we use it in production. I assume it also works with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp, however I can't confirm those.